# Why is my app crashes using __autoreleasing + __strong?

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool, strong-references

Here is my code:

```
void autoreleasingReturn (NSError * __autoreleasing *error)
{
    // --- Crashing
    *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

    // --- Not crashing
//    *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"hello"
//                                 code:-1
//                             userInfo:@{}];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSError __strong *error = nil;

        autoreleasingReturn(&error);

        NSLog(@"error: %@", error); // crash!
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Traces (sorry, can not copy-paste):

[image]

The question is: what is going on?

I need details on what is going on in this code. Really interesting...
Instruments don't show any leaks, zombies etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initWithDomain:code:userInfo:` is the designated initializer for NSError. That means don't call plain `init`.

You would get the same crash just by saying this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSError alloc] init]);
```

The problem has nothing to do with automatic ref counting, autorelease, autorelease pool, strong, or any of that other stuff! It's just that you are making a bad NSError object and then trying to log it.

Comment: Can you explain me, whats going there under the hood?

Comment: Yes, I can! :) NSLog is crashing you. You're making an invalid NSError object. When you try to log it, NSLog sends your NSError object the `description` message. But it is invalid so it has no `description`.

Comment: (Well, it has a `description` method, but that method calls `localizedDescription` and that's the source of the problem.)

Comment: I would argue that this is a library bug. It should throw an exception, either at initialization time, or at `description` time.

Comment: Or `init` should call the designated initializer with reasonable default arguments. I'll file a bug if you will!

Comment: We investigated the same error, `[[NSError alloc] init]` creates a broken `NSError` object, that crashes when calling `-description` or `-localizedDescription`. The fact that `-initWithDomain:code:userInfo:` is the designated initializer doesn't mean by any way that using other initializers is bad. The framework should either properly handle `NSError`s without `domain` or raise an exception when initializing an `NSError` without domain.